# Where to find STORIES about successes with Attachment Disorders

Tags: emotion-focused-therapy

I'm reading about Emotion Focused Therapy and Attachment Disorders.
Often this is so analytical it's hard to apply it to the "real world".

It occurs to me that reading stories about real people dealing with any sort of emotional difficulties would be a helpful way to understand & apply the concepts.

**I've tried** googling on "patient stories, EFT, Attachment" but I'm getting research on the value of stories/narratives, not the actual stories.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but what real benefit can you get from anecdotal reports on how it works over the articles and books you can read about how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for case studies based on results from The Adult Attachment Interview (Mary Main). This will help you in finding "real-life" stories, that are interpreted using key concepts, such as coherence and reflective functioning.

Try this to start linking attachment concepts to emotion focused therapy. [Cordeiro (2019)](http://yorkspace.library.yorku.ca/xmlui/handle/10315/36330) examines influence of the AAI on parent-child emotion focused therapy.

### References

Cordeiro, K. M. (2019). *Engaging Caregivers in the Service of Their Child's Mental Health: An Examination of Emotion-Focused Family Therapy and the Adult Attachment Interview.* http://yorkspace.library.yorku.ca/xmlui/handle/10315/36330